# python-gitlab : How to list all issues in a specific milestone

Tags: python, gitlab, python-gitlab

I need some help. how to list all issues in a specific milestone? this is my script

```
group = gl.groups.get(53)
for project in group.milestones.list(search='TestMilestone'):
    print(project)

group = gl.groups.get(53)
for issues in group.milestone.issues(search='TestMilestone'):
    print(issues)
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work:

```
group.issues.list(milestone='TestMilestone')
```

see https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/issues.html#id2